# Getting JS over to another view with EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, object, ejs

I would appreciate a hand here, probably an easy one, but its late and Im beat. I think I need a second set of eyes on this.

username is the variable I am trying to pass, I am new so not sure of etiquette, I assume less code is best in my post so ill just put my .post and then link my git hub in case anyone wants to see the rest of the relevant code.

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-success">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/urls">TinyApp</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/urls">My URLs</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/urls/new">Create New URL</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   <p>
    ***<% username %>*** 
   </p>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I commented out an if statement, didnt seem to work, wasn't exactly causing the code to break tho either.

```
//redirect to index page after 'login'
app.post('/index', (req, res) => {
  // if (req.cookies["username"]) {
  //   let templateVars = { urls: urlDatabase, username: req.body.username };
  // } else {
  //   let templateVars = { urls: urlDatabase };
  // }
  res.cookie('username', req.body.username);
  let templateVars = { username: req.body.username }; 

  console.log(templateVars.username);
  res.redirect('urls', 200,  templateVars);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `res.redirect()` properly.  The function signature is this:

```
res.redirect([status,] path)
```

It takes two arguments only, an optional status code and a URL or path to redirect the browser to.  You aren't passing any of those arguments properly.

A normal use of `res.redirect()` would look like this:

```
res.redirect("/home");
```

If you leave out the status, it will default to 302.

---

Perhaps you meant to be doing:

```
res.render('urls', templateVars);
```

which would render a template named `urls` using the `templateVars` object as properties for the template and that would be returned as the new HTML document to display after the form POST that caused this request?

---

If what you were trying to do is to redirect to another url and then have it somehow use `templateVars` to render after the redirect, you cannot do that this way.

Comment: awesome thanks for the input! I definitely need to be using .render, I guess because it should be the first time that page gets loaded. The username is getting stored and as far as my console is telling me I am at least loading it into templateVars, and attempting to pass it over to the other view. The issue seems to be that my partial is getting an undefined variable. Going to try to fix that part now.